# Wordpress: Get ID from wp_query post for jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, parentid

**I have a code:**

```
<div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="first">
```

**and I want to use it in JQuery for click function, like:**

```
$('#parent-**??**').click(function (){
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You won't be able to guess dynamic IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value from PHP to JS:

PHP:

```
echo sprintf("<script> var theID = %d;</script>", the_ID());
<div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="first">
```

JS:

```
 <script>
   alert("current post id = "+theID);
 </script>
```

UPDATE:

In case you are printing posts in a loop, you may want to push all the ids into an array.

PHP:

```
<?php
$posts = [];
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        ?>
        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="first">
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
        </div>
        <?php
        posts[] = get_the_ID();
    } 
}

echo sprintf("<script> var thePostIDs = %s;</script>", json_encode(posts));
```

JS:

```
<script>
    thePostIDs.map(function(id){
     // do something with the id
     $('#parent-'+id).click(function (){
       // do something
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its not work for me. When i use `<div id="parent-<?php echo sprintf("<script> var theID = %d;</script>", the_ID()); ?>" class="first">` and get the script to JS...

Comment: mixing PHP + JS is always a bad idea .. much better to use data-* tags

Comment: Could you please update your post and show your actual code? it is hard to guess why exactly your code does not work

Comment: Eriks, sorry for delay. I dont know where was the problem, but I just found the solution without jquery. Anyway, thank you for your help and time...

Comment: @admiva you should post your answer and mark as accepted - don't accept an answer that didn't solve your issue (though, it does look like an ok answer - still, much better to post your findings)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get dynamically generated DOM attributes. jQuery, whilst it can get the value using AJAX, it's a bit of an overhead to do that. The best thing IMO is to simply assign the ID to a hidden element with a generic class. In your jQuery you can then use the generic class to get the dynamic value and append that to the jQuery selector to get the dynamic element.

If you can change the HTML, you could do this:

```
<div id="hidden-parent" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"></div>

<div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="first">
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
let id = $('#hidden-parent').attr('data-id'),
    parentDiv = $('#parent-'+ id);

parentDiv.click(function()
{
    //whatever
})
```

here we just get the `data-id` value and use that to get the parent-* div

There is one thing to note about this. If you're looping divs to build a page then using an ID on the hidden-parent element won't work. What you could do is append the key, e.g.

```
<?php foreach ($elements as $key => $el) : ?>
    <div id="foo-<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <!-- etc. -->
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then in your jQuery just use `$('#foo-1')` etc.

Comment: to downvoter, leave a comment so I can better my answer :)

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="first parent" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<script>
    $('.parent').click(function (){
         var parentId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        if (parentId != undefined && parentId != '') {
            // do something
        }

     });
</script>
```

Comment: code only answers aren't answers IMO - it should consist of an explanation of the problem and solution.

Comment: IMO people here looking for answers, if they want to learn something, they can research and solve by themselves

Comment: If that's your attitude, then, don't answer, as they won't learn anything from just code